# async/await and the IDisposable interface

Tags: c#, async-await, idisposable

I have a class which implements the IDisposable interface to dispose a private variable `_MailMessage` The same class has a async method that makes use of the private IDisposable variable, namely `async public Task<bool> Send` My question is: Will the normal IDisposable implementation dispose the private variable after the async method completes? Here is an example of the class I am talking about:

```
public class Email : IEmail
{
    private readonly IEmailData _EmailData;
    private MailMessage _MailMessage = new MailMessage();

    public Email(IEmailData emailData)
    {
        if (emailData == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailData");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailData.To))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailData.To");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailData.From))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailData.From");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailData.FromName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailData.FromName");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailData.Subject))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailData.Subject");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailData.Body))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailData.Body");
        }

        _EmailData = emailData;
    }


    async public Task<bool> Send()
    {
        return await Task.Run<bool>(() =>
        {
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.Send(_MailMessage);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    #region "IDisposable implementation"
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    ~Email()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_MailMessage != null)
                _MailMessage.Dispose();
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

I have changed the IDisposable implementation according to one of the answer that suggest not to use a destructor:

```
#region "IDisposable implementation"
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (_MailMessage != null)
            _MailMessage.Dispose();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are doing it pretty fundamentally wrong.  A good rule to keep in mind that if you *think* that you need a destructor then you're wrong 99.9% of the time.  A destructor is only required if you have a private variable of an unmanaged type that needs to be released.  You don't.  The way that you can tell you are doing it wrong is when you find out that you are not actually doing anything at all if the *disposing* argument is false.  Or in other words, the destructor doesn't actually do anything.  So it isn't needed.  Then you don't need the disposable pattern either.

There's more wrongness, you need to inherit the IDisposable interface to implement your own Dispose() method.  You forgot.

Your Dispose() method needs to be called by the client code that creates an instance of your Email class.  You cannot call it yourself, you don't know when the client code stops using your Email object.  So that's a quick answer to your question, you cannot dispose yourself in the Send() method.  There's no guarantee whatsoever that the client code will actually call it.  You will have to leave it up to the client code to get it right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to find out if a private variable is of an unmanaged type?

The IDispose interface is inherited in the IEmail interface, so that should be good I guess.

What do you mean with "You cannot call it yourself". Where do I call it myself?

Comment: I changed the IDisposable implementation according to your answer, effectively removed the destructor. But is the IDisposable completely unnecessary? And if so, why?

Comment: No, it is not unnecessary since you *do* have a disposable member.  You own the MailMessage object.

Comment: It's possible that the class does inherit from `IDisposable` indirectly, though `IEmail`.

Answer (score 15):

I don't see anywhere you're explicitly disposing `_MailMessage` other than in `Email.Dispose`.

`async` doesn't do anything particularly magical with `IDispose`; the only thing you have to keep in mind is that `async` methods may return early.

So if you call it like this:

```
using (var email = new Email(...))
{
  await email.Send();
}
```

Then your calling code will (asynchronously) wait for `Send` to complete before disposing `email`. But if you call it like this:

```
Task task;
using (var email = new Email(...))
{
  task = email.Send();
}
```

Then your calling code will dispose `email` before `Send` completes.

Comment: The thing that worries me a bit is that the private variable is used in this statement: () => 

Will it create a in memory copy or.. how does this work?