# Cancel running Tasks on Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I've got a class with a few Async methods that accept a `CancellationToken` and return a `Task` - where some of these tasks may literally run forever.

I also need a `Dispose()` method as I deal with unmanaged objects, but am not sure how to *properly* implement the `Dispose()`.

Clearly I can't `Dispose()` and let the tasks continue run in the background, but I can't just block the `Dispose()` until the they complete either as they might never complete altogether.

The only alternative I see is to create a linked `CancellationTokenSource` from the given `CancellationToken` and, on `Dispose()` to use it to cancel any outstanding tasks.

However that feels unnatural in that I'd be marking the consumer given `CancellationToken` as cancelled - ultimately isn't this something *the consumer* should be in charge of?

Am I missing something and is there a more natural way of performing this, am I overthinking the problem?

Comment: I think you are overthinking the problem. It makes complete sense to me that running tasks throw `TaskCancelledException` when their object gets `Disposed`

Comment: But how would they come to throw `TaskCancelledException`?

Comment: This was asked for sure, google for `async IDisposable`, e.g. [here are some thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18849825/1997232). You can just write own `Task<T> Dispose()` method and call it, you don't really need `IDisposable`: it's only good for static code analysis and `using`.

Comment: You would have to deal with that i.e. by combining a token that the class owns with a token the consumer provides. But isn't this an edge case at all? The class should be disposed by the owner which usually is the creator of the instance. In my opinion the owner will most likely also consume the class thus it should also take care of the lifecycle.

Comment: @Sinatr I need `IDisposable` because an object I use is `IDisposable`. I don't need a finalizer though. I don't think that linked question really covers my case.

Comment: If you cannot have tasks running when object is disposed - you have to choose one option you described in your question. Option with linked cancellation token source looks allright for me.

Comment: Sounds a little bit X/Y. You should probably refactor this class, you should not have the mgmt of Tasks/Threads and other resources lumped together.